# ggplot: plotting two variables into a single facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization, reshape

Goal: I am studying basic trends of currency conversion with the help of `ggplot`. I'm able to achieve the initially intended idea to plot the monthly trends of closing and average rates. *(closing - signifies the closing rate at end of each month; average - signifies the average rate of conversion in the month to date)*. However, I'm looking for suggestions to enhance the plot for better representation.

Expected: From the plot attached below, it makes more sense to visualize the closing and average rates comparison of the same currency in a single facet.

Here's the sample reproducible code:

```
library(ggplot2, quietly = TRUE)
library(reshape2,  quietly = TRUE)
library(data.table,  quietly = TRUE)
library(readxl,  quietly = TRUE)


#Monthly data for closing and average rates of currency conversion.

#Note: For representation purposes, I've just increased the average rates by 5% of the closing rates.

data = data.frame("Month_Name" = c("Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov"), 
"USD_INR_Closing" = c(69.565, 69.68, 69.02, 68.795, 71.405, 70.875, 70.925,71.745),
"EUR_USD_Closing" = c(1.1213972545, 1.1148464413, 1.1377137056, 1.1148339268, 1.1037392343, 1.0908994712, 1.1162143115, 1.1002508891),
"USD_INR_Average" = c(73.04325, 73.164, 72.471, 72.23475, 74.97525, 74.41875, 74.47125, 75.33225), 
"EUR_USD_Average" = c(1.1774671172, 1.1705887633, 1.1945993909, 1.1705756232, 1.158926196, 1.1454444447, 1.1720250271, 1.1552634336) ) 



# Performing transformation
df <- melt(data, id.vars = 'Month_Name', measure.vars = c("USD_INR_Closing" , "EUR_USD_Closing", "USD_INR_Average", "EUR_USD_Average"),
           variable.name = "Conversion", value.name = "Currency")

f <- function(x){
  format(round(x, 3), nsmall=1)
}

# Generating a plot in dersire format with N panes. (N = number of currency conversions required to display) 
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(df$Month_Name, levels = unique(df$Month_Name)), y=Currency, group=1)) + 
  geom_line() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5),
                                 panel.spacing = unit(0.8, "lines"), 
                                 panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, size = 0.8),
                                 ) +  
  facet_grid(Conversion ~ ., scales = 'free_y')+
  ggtitle("Currency Conversion Trends")+
  ylab("Conversion Rate")+xlab("Month")+
   geom_text(
       size = 3.0,
       fontface='bold',
       aes(label = sprintf("%0.2f", round(Currency, digits = 2)), y = Currency),
       vjust = +0.3,
       #nudge_y = 0.01,
       nudge_x = 0.35,
     )+
  geom_point(shape=21, color="black", fill="#69b3a2", size=3)
```

Here's the output plot:

[image]

In the given scenario, how can I plot the line graphs of `USD_INR_Closing` and `USD_INR_Average` into a single facet *(comparing closing vs. average)* and apply the same for other currency conversions?

Comment: Create one group such as Type (Average, Closing) and another group Currency (USD_INR, EUR_USD) then use them for assigning color or facet group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @Tung and @Parfait and especially @Tjebo for guiding in the right direction.

Here's the anticipated output, achieved through the below code:

```
library(tidyverse,  quietly = TRUE)
library(ggrepel,  quietly = TRUE)

mydf = data.frame("Month_Name" = c("Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov"), 
                  "USD_INR_Closing" = c(69.565, 69.68, 69.02, 68.795, 71.405, 70.875, 70.925,71.745),
                  "EUR_USD_Closing" = c(1.1213972545, 1.1148464413, 1.1377137056, 1.1148339268, 1.1037392343, 1.0908994712, 1.1162143115, 1.1002508891),
                  "USD_INR_Average" = c(73.04325, 73.164, 72.471, 72.23475, 74.97525, 74.41875, 74.47125, 75.33225), 
                  "EUR_USD_Average" = c(1.1774671172, 1.1705887633, 1.1945993909, 1.1705756232, 1.158926196, 1.1454444447, 1.1720250271, 1.1552634336) ) 

mydf2 <- pivot_longer(mydf, cols =USD_INR_Closing:EUR_USD_Average, names_to = "Conversion", values_to = "Currency")  %>% 
  mutate(Month_Name = factor(Month_Name, levels = month.abb)) %>%
  separate(Conversion, into = c('from','to','measure'))

ggplot(mydf2, aes(x = factor(mydf2$Month_Name, levels = unique(mydf2$Month_Name)), y = Currency, group = measure, colour = measure )) + 
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("Currency Conversion Trends - Average vs. Closing Rates")+
  ylab("Conversion Rate")+xlab("Month")+
  geom_point(shape=21, color="black", fill="#69b3a2", size=2) +
  geom_text_repel(size = 2.8,
                  fontface='bold',
                  aes(label = sprintf("%0.2f", round(Currency, digits = 2)), y = Currency),
                  box.padding = 0.25,
                  direction = 'both' )+
  facet_wrap(~ interaction(from,to), ncol = 1, scales = 'free_y')
```

Output Plot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of unnecessary code, and your code is also not working. I would always recommend to reproduce it in an empty session..
Create a new grouping variable first.
**edit**
After some consideration of my first approach to use a logical statement for grouping, I have changed the way to create the different groups, using `tidyr::separate`. This generally cleans up your data and you can work better with its variables. For grouping, I used `interaction`.

I also use the R constant `month.abb` to factorise your Month column.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydf <- data.frame(
  "Month_Name" = c("Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov"),
  "USD_INR_Closing" = c(69.565, 69.68, 69.02, 68.795, 71.405, 70.875, 70.925, 71.745),
  "EUR_USD_Closing" = c(1.1213972545, 1.1148464413, 1.1377137056, 1.1148339268, 1.1037392343, 1.0908994712, 1.1162143115, 1.1002508891),
  "USD_INR_Average" = c(73.04325, 73.164, 72.471, 72.23475, 74.97525, 74.41875, 74.47125, 75.33225),
  "EUR_USD_Average" = c(1.1774671172, 1.1705887633, 1.1945993909, 1.1705756232, 1.158926196, 1.1454444447, 1.1720250271, 1.1552634336)
)

mydf2 <- pivot_longer(mydf, cols =USD_INR_Closing:EUR_USD_Average, names_to = "Conversion", values_to = "Currency")  %>% 
  mutate(Month_Name = factor(Month_Name, levels = month.abb)) %>%
  separate(Conversion, into = c('from','to','type'))

ggplot(mydf2, aes(x = Month_Name, y = Currency, group = type)) + 
  geom_line() +  
  geom_point(shape=21, color="black", fill="#69b3a2", size=3) +
  facet_wrap(~ interaction(from,to), scales = 'free_y')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: `TRUE` and `FALSE`?

Comment: True but goes without saying that labeling on graphs should be informative for readers. Try assigning named values in `mutate` as: `metric = ifelse(grepl('INR', Conversion), 'INR', ifelse(grepl('USD', Conversion), 'USD', NA)) ... facet_grid(~metric, scales = 'free_y')`

Comment: @Parfait after consideration I have changed the approach entirely.

Comment: @Tjebo: I thought OP needed to distinguish between closing vs. average values as well?

Comment: @Tung OP wanted to compare closing vs. average for each exchange group within one facet - Closings are the bottom lines, average the top lines.

Comment: @Tjebo: Thanks for taking the time in answering my query. The sample code works fine, after the edit by Jonathan. 

Based on your approach, the comparison between closed vs. average values is achieved within a single facet. Appreciate it. However, if there are more than 2 currencies, then replicating months for every facet would take lot of space on the plane. 

Do you have further recommendations on shifting the the facets horizontally, by fixing my x-axis _(Month_Name)_ as constant across currencies/facets ?

Comment: @PradeepVaranasi it is not quite clear to me what you are exactly trying to achieve. This may warrant a follow up question. If you decide to ask one, please don't forget to refer to the previous one.

Comment: @Tjebo I shall post a follow-up question in case you are not clear with the following explanation. **USD.INR** and **EUR.USD** are on the same timeline _(Apr to Nov )_ on the x-axis _(Month_Name)_. Visualizing the facets vertically would create redundant timelines as the number of conversions increase. Hence, it would be accurate if the facets representing currencies be in a horizontal grid with a single/fixed x-axis _(Month_Name)_, like in the OP output plot.

Comment: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html see here how to define rows and columns. also consider `facet_wrap`. If this does not help - please post new question